# Other representation of Gamma Incomplete function

Tags: gamma-function

I have a question regarding Gamma Incomplete function:

In the "Table of Integrals, Series, and Products, Seventh Edition" equation $8.353.3$ page $900$, there is a defenition for the incomplete gamma function in the case $a < 1$ and $x > 0$

$$ \Gamma(a,x)=\frac{\rho^{-x}x^{a}}{\Gamma(1-a)} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t} t^{-a}}{x+t} dt$$

what is $ \rho $ in the above equation? I thought this might be a but I tried to derive the above formula but I don't got the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\Gamma\pars{a,x} = {\expo{-x}x^{a} \over \Gamma\pars{1 - a}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-t}t^{-a} \over x + t}\,\dd t:\ {\Large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#f00}{\Gamma\pars{a,x}\Gamma\pars{1 - a}}=
> \int_{x}^{\infty}\dd t\,t^{a - 1}\expo{-t}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd t'\,
> t'^{\pars{1 - a} - 1}\expo{-t'}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{x^{1/2}}^{\infty}\dd t\,\pars{2t}t^{2a - 2}\expo{-t^{2}}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}\dd t'\,\pars{2t'}t'^{-2a}\expo{-t'^{2}}
> \\[3mm]&=4\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{t - x^{1/2}}t^{2a - 1}
> t'^{1 - 2a}\expo{-\pars{t^{2} + t'^{2}}}\,\dd t\,\dd t'
> \\[3mm]&=4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dd\theta\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd r\,r\,
> \Theta\pars{r\cos\pars{\theta} - x^{1/2}}r^{2a - 1}\cos^{2a - 1\pars{\theta}}
> r^{1 - 2a}\sin^{1 - 2a}\pars{\theta}\expo{-r^{2}}
> \\[3mm]&=4\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd r\,r\expo{-r^{2}}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dd\theta\,
> \Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} - {x^{1/2} \over r}}\cos^{2a -1}\pars{\theta}
> \sin^{1 - 2a}\pars{\theta}
> \\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd t\,\expo{-t}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\dd\theta\,
> \Theta\pars{\cos\pars{\theta} - \bracks{x \over t}^{1/2}}\cos^{2a -1}\pars{\theta}
> \sin^{1 - 2a}\pars{\theta}
> \\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd t\,\expo{-t}\int_{0}^{1}\dd t'\,
> \Theta\pars{t' - \bracks{x \over t}^{1/2}}t'^{2a - 1}\pars{1 - t'^{2}}^{-a}
> \\[3mm]&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd t\,\expo{-t}\int_{0}^{1}\dd t'\,\half\,t'^{-1/2}
> \Theta\pars{t' - {x \over t}}t'^{a - 1/2}\pars{1 - t'}^{-a}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd t\,\expo{-t}\int_{0}^{1}\dd t'\,
> \Theta\pars{tt' - x}t'^{a - 1}\pars{1 - t'}^{-a}
> =\int_{0}^{1}\dd t'\,t'^{a - 1}\pars{1 - t'}^{-a}\int_{x/t'}^{\infty}\dd t\,\expo{-t}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}\dd t'\,t'^{a - 1}\pars{1 - t'}^{-a}\expo{-x/t'}
> =\int_{\infty}^{1}t^{1 - a}\pars{1 - {1 \over t}}^{-a}\expo{-xt}\,
> \pars{-\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{-1}\pars{t - 1}^{-a}\expo{-xt}\,\dd t
> =\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{-a} \over t + 1}\expo{-x\pars{t + 1}}\,\dd t
> =\expo{-x}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-xt}t^{-a} \over t + 1}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=
> \color{#f00}{\expo{-x}x^{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-t}t^{-a} \over t + x}\,\dd t}
> \end{align}

Then
$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\Gamma\pars{a,x} = {\expo{-x}x^{a} \over \Gamma\pars{1 - a}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-t}t^{-a} \over x + t}\,\dd t}
$$

Comment: Wow, that must have been painful!

Comment: @JPi Yes. I went back and forth before I saw the right road. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It should be $e$.  See the Handbook of Mathematical Functions, 8.6.4.

Comment: Do you mean "Handbook of Mathematical Functions with Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables  1970" By Milton Abramowitz, Irene A. Stegun?
Page 334 equation 8.6.4 is it related to my case?

Comment: No, the NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions by Olver et al..  It is identical to your case except that $\rho$ in your formula is $e$ in theirs.