# Seeking Methods to solve $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^n}}{x^n + 1}\:dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

As an extension of a question I posed [earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042183/methods-to-solve-int-0-infty-frace-x2x2-1-dx), I thought it would be best to try and final the result for a more general form:

\begin{equation}
I_n = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^n}}{x^n + 1}\:dx 
\end{equation}
with $n \in \mathbb{R}, n > 1$

As with the previous question, I'm interested in finding alternative ways of solving this that does not rely on complex analysis.

My Method: I employ the exact same method as with my earlier question. Here first let

\begin{equation}
J_n(t) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-tx^n}}{x^n + 1}\:dx 
\end{equation}

We see that $I_n = J_n(1)$ and that $J_n(0) = \frac{1}{n}\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ (This is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042291/int-0-infty-frac11-xn-dx-frac1n-gamma-left-fracn-1))

Now, take the derivative with respect to '$t$' to achieve
\begin{align}
 J_n'(t) &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{-x^ne^{-tx^n}}{x^n + 1}\:dx = -\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\left(x^n + 1 - 1\right)e^{-tx^n}}{x^n + 1}\:dx \\
&= -\left[\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-tx^n}\:dx - \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-tx^n}}{x^n + 1}\:dx   \right] \\
&= -\left[ \frac{t^{-\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) -J_n(t)\right]
\end{align}

Which yields the differential equation:

\begin{equation}
 J_n'(t) - J_n(t) = -\frac{t^{-\frac{1}{n}}}{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{equation}

Which yields the solution:

\begin{equation}
 J_n(t) = \frac{1}{n}\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}, t\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)e^t
\end{equation}

And finally:

\begin{equation}
 I_n = J_n(1) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^n}}{x^n + 1}\:dx = \frac{e}{n}\Gamma\left(1 - \frac{1}{n}, 1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
\end{equation}

Which for me, is a nice result. Fascinated to see other methods!

Edit - Thanks to [spaceisdarkgreen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/397125/spaceisdarkgreen) for the pickup on my mistyping of the Incomplete Gamma Function.

Comment: @J.G. - re reflection. I was hoping to have a result for all non zero real values.

Comment: That doesn't look quite right to me... the first Gamma function should be an incomplete Gamma with lower bound $z=1.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen - Thank you! yes yes, I mean't to type it as the incomplete beta at $z = 1$. Thanks for the pick up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can offer a shorter way to obtain the final result in terms of the Incomplete  Gamma Function. Therby consider the following representation of the Incomplete Gamma Function which can be found [here on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687605/other-representation-of-gamma-incomplete-function)

> $$ \Gamma(a,x)=\frac{e^{-x}x^{a}}{\Gamma(1-a)} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t} t^{-a}}{x+t} dt\tag1$$

Getting back to your original integral and applying the substitution $x^n=t$ yields to the following

$$\begin{align}
I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^n}}{x^n + 1}dx&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t}}{1+t}\frac1nt^{1/n-1}dt\\
&=\frac1n\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}t^{-(1-1/n)}}{1+t}dt
\end{align}$$

The latter integral is in the form of $(1)$ with $a=1-1/n$ and $x=1$ from where we can conclude that

$$\begin{align}
I_n=\frac1n\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t}t^{-(1-1/n)}}{1+t}dt=\frac1n\frac{\Gamma\left(1-\frac1n,1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac1n\right)}{e^{-1}}
\end{align}$$

> $$I_n=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^n}}{x^n + 1}dx=\frac en\Gamma\left(1-\frac1n,1\right)\Gamma\left(\frac1n\right)$$

Of course this way of solving requires the knowledge of formula $(1)$ $($an impressive proof done by the user *Felix Marin* can be found within the linked post$)$ but nevertheless this evaluation method is quite compact.

Answer (score 3):

I will offer up ([again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042183/methods-to-solve-int-0-infty-frace-x2x2-1-dx/3042430#3042430)) a method that coverts the integral to a double integral. Note for convergence of the integral we require $n > 0$.

For $n > 0$, begin by enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto x^{1/n}$. This gives
$$I_n = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/n -1} e^{-x}}{1 + x} \, dx \qquad (1)$$

Noting that 
$$\frac{1}{x + 1} = \int_0^\infty e^{-u(x + 1)} \, du,$$
the integral in (1) can be rewritten as
$$I_n = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty x^{1/n - 1} e^{-x} \int_0^\infty e^{-u(x + 1)} \, du \, dx,$$
or 
$$I_n = \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty e^{-u} \int_0^\infty x^{1/n - 1} e^{-x(u + 1)} \, dx \, du,$$
on changing the order of integration.

Enforcing a substitution of $x \mapsto x/(u + 1)$ leads to
\begin{align}
I_n &= \frac{1}{n} \int_0^\infty (u + 1)^{-1/n} e^{-u} \int_0^\infty x^{1/n - 1} e^{-x} \, dx \, du\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{n} \right ) \int_0^\infty (u + 1)^{-1/n} e^{-u} \, du.
\end{align} 
Finally, enforcing a substitution of $u \mapsto u - 1$ one has
$$I_n = \frac{e}{n} \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{n} \right ) \int_1^\infty u^{(1 - 1/n) - 1} e^{-u} \, du = \frac{e}{n} \Gamma \left (\frac{1}{n} \right ) \Gamma \left (1 - \frac{1}{n}, 1 \right ),$$
as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. As discussed, I'm still developing my integral 'expansion' skills so it's great to see multiple examples. Please keep posting them up :-)

Comment: Sure thing. Glad I can be of some help. Of course the conversion of an improper integral to a double integral is not always possible or appropriate, but like I said before, is a nice trick to have up one's sleeve.