# How do I evaluate $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^\alpha(1+x^\alpha)} \mathrm dx$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, integration

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^\alpha(1+x^\alpha)} \mathrm dx &= 
\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\left(\frac{1+x^\alpha}{x^\alpha(1+x^\alpha)}  -  \frac{x^\alpha}{x^\alpha(1+x^\alpha)}\right)dx\\ &= \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^\alpha} \mathrm dx - \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{1+x^\alpha} \mathrm dx
\end{align*}

So I get :

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x^\alpha} \mathrm dx = \Gamma(\alpha-1)$$

But I don´t know how to evaluate :

$$- \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{1+x^\alpha} \mathrm dx$$

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3042335/seeking-methods-to-solve-int-0-infty-frace-xnxn-1-dx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: It does look good regarding a closed-form. Experimenting, especially after enforcing the substitution $1/x\mapsto x$, seems that for $\alpha=2$ there is [some kind of closed-form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E(infinity)+1%2F(1%2Bx%5E2)*e%5E(-x)) involving the Sine and the Cosine Integral. However, for $\alpha=3$ and greater WolframAlpha does not produce anything at all. I do not even know how to get started for $\alpha\notin\mathbb N$.

Comment: If that helps, the integral can be evaluated in terms of the Fox H-function in the same way as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104763).

Comment: @Maxim -  was just about to link my question! :-)

Comment: I found the solution, but have no time to test it. First substitution 1/x->x, then express $\frac{1}{x^{2}}\frac{x^{\alpha }}{x^{\alpha }+1}$ by a MeijerG-Function. Then set: $\alpha = l/k$ and use http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/MeijerG/21/02/07/0005/. If you need the general solution just change the MeijerG - Function by a H-Fox-Function https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266566090_The_H-function_Theory_and_Applications. If you need more help, please let me know

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution of $x\rightarrow \frac{1}{y}$ the integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\exp \left( -y\right) \frac{y^{\alpha -2}}{1+y^{\alpha }}dy$$

can be interpreted as a laplace transformation of

$$\mathcal{L}\left\{ \frac{y^{\alpha -2}}{1+y^{\alpha }}\right\} =\mathcal{L}%
\left\{ y^{\alpha -2}G_{1,1}^{1,1}\left( y^{\alpha }\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 
0%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) \right\} $$
for $s=1$. Here the integrand is expressed in form of a Meijer $G$ -
function. With the help of [Mathai](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266566090_The_H-function_Theory_and_Applications) (2.29,p. 52) the solution can be expressed

$$\mathcal{L}\left[ y^{\alpha -2}G_{1,1}^{1,1}\left( y^{\alpha }\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 
0%
\end{array}%
\right. \right) \right] \overset{s\rightarrow 1}{=}H_{3,2}^{1,3}\left(
1\left\vert 
\begin{array}{c}
\left( 0,1\right) ,\left( 0,1\right) ,\left( 2-\alpha ,\alpha \right)  \\ 
\left( 0,1\right) ,\left( 0,1\right) 
\end{array}%
\right. \right) $$
by a $H$ - Fox function.

Comment: The change of variables gives $e^{-y} y^{2 \alpha - 2}/(1 + y^\alpha)$. Also, notice that the H-function can be simplified to $H_{2, 1}^{1, 2}$ by cancelling two identical factors.

Comment: @Maxim you are right, thank you very much for this note. First I consider the  Plancherel theorem and the  laplace of Dotsenko function and had not much time left. I also consider the last integral of the question after "how to evaluate:"

Comment: I see, I was thinking about the integral in the title. So the answer for that integral is $\Gamma(\alpha - 1)$ minus your final result, with the condition $\alpha > 1$. Then you can argue that this still holds for $\alpha > 1/2$ by analytic continuation.